# How to fill minHeight or minWidth in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let's say I have the following layout:

```
VStack {
  Text(title)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

  Spacer()

  Divider()
    .frame(height: 1)
}
.frame(minHeight: 80, alignment: .bottom)
```

I want the text field to expand freely, divider to be aligned to the bottom, and the whole thing to be at least 80 points tall (but not taller if not necessary). If I leave it like this the spacer will take up all of the parent's height (exceeding 80). If I don't have a spacer, both subviews will be aligned together to the top, bottom, or center.

How can I achieve desired spacer behaviour? Or maybe the layout should be structured differently?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured out a simpler solution for the desired result if I use ZStack instead of spacer like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text(title)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

    Text(description)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  }.frame(minHeight: 80)

  Divider()
    .frame(height: 1)
}
```

Then, if I want to make sure that the first view in ZStack doesn't overlap the second one, I could use solution proposed by Anton Agafonov and insert a spacer into the VStack with height calculated based on the second child of ZStack.

Comment: The `ZStack` has nothing to do with this. Make it a `VStack` will result the same! The point is to add the frame to the content instead of the container Stack which I told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76573521/5623035)

Comment: I don't understand why you insist on your answer and downvote a solution that works for me when your solution clearly doesn't result in a view with height of 80 regardless of the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can create any views and observe their content height/width using PreferenceKey. Depending on your request you might use different conditions, for example in my piece of code - viewHeight:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var title = "TitleTitleTitleTitle"
    @State private var textHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var viewHeight: CGFloat {
        if textHeight < 80 {
            return 80
        } else {
            return textHeight
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(
                                key: TextHeightKey.self,
                                value: geometry.size.height
                            )
                    }
                )
            
            Spacer()
            
            Divider()
                .frame(height: 1)
        }
        .frame(height: viewHeight, alignment: .bottom)
        .onPreferenceChange(TextHeightKey.self) { height in
            textHeight = height
        }
    }
}

struct TextHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = max(value, nextValue())
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but in order to keep to overlay constraint of entire view >= 80 without assuming size of any of the subviews, geometry reader would have to be applied to each of them. My actual use is a bit more complex than this therefore the calculation would get unwieldy rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a hight of 80 or more if needed, right?

Since it depends on the text, why don't you assign the minimum height to the `Text` itself and get rid of the `Spacer`?

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text(title) //  This is the content and can be a container of any views
        .frame(minHeight: 80)
        .lineLimit(0)

    Divider()
}
```

Comment: Because then the height of the entire view isn't 80 anymore. I wrote a simple example, but imagine that there is two or more text views (or other views). I'd like to know how and if it's possible to create a view with such constraint, not to create something visually similar.

Comment: I can't understand your need without more context. Please show at least 3 states of the desired layouts.

Comment: It seems you showed another sample in an answer! You can put a container around anything you need to be at least 80 like you do with a container `VStack`